# Open iPhone/iPad settings panel

Tags: ios, xcode, settings

My app needs feature to open iPhone/iPad "Mail, contacts, Calendars" settings panel and automatically scroll to view default calendar settings row. Any sample or idea?

I will put it under the IBAction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL scheme for programmatically launching Settings.app to a particular settings panel was briefly exposed (though I'm not sure if it was documented) in iOS 5. However, the capability has been suppressed for third-party apps in iOS 5.1. As it stands, there is currently no way to do this from a third-party app on the latest version of the OS - at least, not in a way that won't get your app rejected from the App Store. There's likely a jailbreak way to do this, but I don't dabble in that, so I wouldn't know.