# Open Settings Programmatically iOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am making an app in which I need to open settings of device programatically. Previously we can open it using following code

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

But I come to know its been deprecated from iOS 5.1. Please let me know if there is some other way to open it.

Comment: You count in private APIs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open iPhone/iPad settings panel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943237/open-iphone-ipad-settings-panel)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple does not provide a URL schema for achieving this.

Comment: In older versions there was an URL schema, from iOS 5.1 onwards it's removed

Comment: Yes, upto ios5.0 it was working after that this one depreciated.