# How to open settings page of iphone throgh my app?

Tags: ios, setting

Actually, I have a button on my app. If user click on it they will see the general setting page of iPhone. Is it possible for iOS 7 or iOS 7.1? If so then how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217949/open-settings-programatically-ios-6/15218212#15218212

Comment: Thanks. So it will not possible from iOS 5 to iOS 7.1 and possible for iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, till now no api provides.

Comment: This is another question. Can I use send button of email in bottom of iPhone screen?